# Unable to run karate feature file in gitlab CIVD

Tags: karate, cicd

I am facing issue while running karate feature file through CICD pipeline.

Just made a simple api call which has authentication and I used basic auth js for passing authentication ( User name and password) . It’s working fine in my local and if I execute same feature in gitlab CICD , I am getting 403 (message :forbidden) error.

Any help is appreciate

Just made a simple api call which has authentication and I used basic auth js for passing authentication ( User name and password) . It’s working fine in my local and if I execute same feature in gitlab CICD , I am getting 403 (message :forbidden) error.

Any help is appreciate

Comment: isn't it obvious that your gitlab server does not have a connection to your test server ? I personally think no one can help you and you have to figure this out yourself. take the help of your it / networking team if needed. it is also quite likely that you need to configure an HTTP proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+http+proxy